# How do I create shallow routes inside a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

How can I setup my routes file to create the following routes:

```
/forums/1/posts           # GET  index
/forums/1/posts           # POST create
/forums/1/posts/new
# ... the other forum posts restful actions

/posts/1/votes            # POST create
/posts/1/votes/1/destroy
```

I tried this way:

```
resources :forums do
  resources :posts
end

resources :posts do
  resources :votes
end
```

This creates redundant `/posts/1` and `/posts/new` urls, not scoped to the `forum`.

I also tried:

```
resources :forums do
  resources :posts do
    resources :votes, only: [:create, :destroy], shallow: true
  end
end
```

But this creates `forums/1/posts/1/votes/create` while I only want `/posts/1/votes/create`.

Basically, I don't want to nest the `votes` resource under the `forums` resource.

```
resources :posts do # would be nice to do resources :posts, none: true, do
  resources :votes
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:none => true` you can use `:only => []`:

```
resources :forums do
  resources :posts
end

resources :posts, :only => [] do
  resources :votes, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```